# Storing data in arrays with file handling

Tags: arrays, string

I have a string array line[] and two more string arrays loc[] and org[].

I am reading from file values of some variables like startIndex , Length.

I am creating a new string array arr[] which contains line[] values and then I am looping for two iterations for loc[] and org[] values to be merged into arr[], depending upon values of startIndex and Length read from file .

Now  I am reading in first iteration values of startIndex and length for loc[] insertion in arr[] and they are inserted.

But now in second iteration I again read values of startIndex and length which is different from previous ones and i have to insert org[] in arr[],  Keeping a check that org[] startIndex does not overlap with previous one, so org[] is not inserted in place where loc[] is already merged.

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you read both the startIndex and length for both arrays `loc[]` and `org[]` in variables like startIndex_loc, length_loc, startIndex_org and length_org.

You'll have to allocate arr the size of array `line[]` + length of loc[] to be copied(`length_loc[]`) + length of org[] to be copied(`length_org`).

Now firstly, you would have inserted the values of line[].

You would then copy `length_loc` elements of loc[] from starting from index `startIndex_loc` into arr[] starting from line.length index.

You would then copy `length_org` elements of org[] from starting from index `startIndex_loc` into arr[] starting from (line.length + length_loc) index.

Check following java code for reference:

```
         Path path = Paths.get("testing.txt");
         Scanner br = new Scanner(path);
         String sCurrentLine;
         int startIndex_loc = br.nextInt();
         int length_loc = br.nextInt();
         int startIndex_org = br.nextInt();
         int length_org = br.nextInt();

         int line[] = {1,2,3,4};
         int org[] = {8,9,10,11};
         int loc[] = {4,8,12,16};

         int[] arr = new int[line.length + length_loc + length_org];
         for(int i = 0; i<line.length; i++){
             arr[i] = line[i];
         }

         for(int i = 0; i<length_loc; i++){
             arr[line.length + i] = loc[startIndex_loc + i];
         }
        for(int i = 0; i<length_org; i++){
             arr[line.length + length_loc + i] = org[startIndex_org + i];
         }
```